# How to select only <thead> and <tbody> content to copy to clipboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, copy-paste

I need to copy from webpage table content to clipboard. Naturally, I'd like to press "select table" button, and all desired content is selected, then user press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>, and here it goes. The trouble that I cannot select BOTH `<thead>` and `<tbody>` content. Right now I have the following code:

```js
    function selectElementContents(el) {
        var body = document.body, range, sel;
        if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
            range = document.createRange();
            sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            try {
                range.selectNodeContents(el);
                sel.addRange(range);
            } catch (e) {
                range.selectNode(el);
                sel.addRange(range);
            }
        } else if (body.createTextRange) {
            range = body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(el);
            range.select();
        }


    };

   function SelectTable () {
       selectElementContents(document.getElementById('resbody'));
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="results">
<caption>Results</caption>
<thead id="reshead">
<th>Column 1</th>
<th>Column 2</th>
<th>Column 3</th>
</thead>
<tbody id="resbody">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<td colspan="3"><button onclick="SelectTable();">Select table</button></td>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Right now code selects table content.

If I'm trying to do something like:

```
var a=document.getElementById('reshead');
var b=document.getElementById('resbody');
var c=a.concat(b);
selectElementContents(c);
```

It doesn't work at all. 
Even

```
var a=document.getElementById('resbody');
    selectElementContents(a);
```

doesn't work :-O Can I do it probably simpler with jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding
`selectElementContents(document.getElementById('reshead'));`
in `selectTable` function and removing line
`sel.removeAllRanges();` 
from `selectElementContents` function so it doesn't override the previously selected area.

See the below modified code snippet, it works for me. Both header and content are get selected

```js
    function selectElementContents(el) {
        var body = document.body, range, sel;
        if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
            range = document.createRange();
            sel = window.getSelection();

            try {
                range.selectNodeContents(el);
                sel.addRange(range);
            } catch (e) {
                range.selectNode(el);
                sel.addRange(range);
            }
        } else if (body.createTextRange) {
            range = body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(el);
            range.select();
        }


    };

   function SelectTable () {
       selectElementContents(document.getElementById('resbody'));
       selectElementContents(document.getElementById('reshead'));
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="results">
<caption>Results</caption>
<thead id="reshead">
<th>Column 1</th>
<th>Column 2</th>
<th>Column 3</th>
</thead>
<tbody id="resbody">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<td colspan="3"><button onclick="SelectTable();">Select table</button></td>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work both in Chrome and Opera. Works only in Firefox (useless for me, Firefox cannot copy table style :-( And doesn't work AT ALL in IE 11.